# Why doesn't return statement end a recursive function in c?

Tags: c, recursion, return

Here is the code I am working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f_b(int n, int a[n]);

int main() {
    int a[4] = { 7, 6, 5, 4 };
    printf("\n return: %d \n", f_b(4, a));
}

int f_b(int n, int a[n]) {
    int m;
    if (n == 1)
        return a[0];
    m = f_b(n - 1, a);
    printf("m:%d", m);
    if (m > a[n - 1]) {
        printf("\n m was greater than the last item\n ");
        return a[n - 1];
    } else
        return m;
}
```

And here is the output it gives:

```
m:7
m was greater than the last item
m:6
m was greater than the last item
m:5
m was greater than the last item

return: 4
```

I was originally thinking that the code block in `f_b` coming after the first `printf` would be unreachable because the recursive part would keep counting down until until `n` is `1`, with would return the first item of the array. I assumed the code would not go past the `m = f_b(n-1, a);` line until it has returned it's last value, then go on to the `if`-`else` statement. It appears that it will go through the `if`-`else` each recursive call?

I noticed the first item of the array was not being returned each time, which prompted me to litter the function with `printf` statements. I don't understand how the line "m was greater than the last item" can be reached so many times when there is also a `return a[n-1]` statement that I would assume jumps out of the the function. I get that it is jumping out of each recursive call but then why wouldn't it always return `a[0]` when it finishes its recursive calls?

Please correct my thinking here as the output (as I see) demonstrates a `return` statement being reached, but also being passed over. Is it being reached so many times because of the recursion? If so, what is stopping the code in the end (because `n` can be counted down indefinitely)

Comment: just considering the title question, `return` jumps back to the return address, which is the address of executable code following the function call. When you dabble in recursion, this appears to be a return to the same function, but in fact it's a return to the previous stack frame. If `funcA` calls `funcB` and `funcB` returns, would you expect `funcA` to exit too? No, `funcA` picks up right after the call to `funcB`. With a recursive call, `funcA` and `funcB` happen to be the same function.

Comment: Each time `f_b(n-1, a)` is called, control is returned to the line following the function call, which is `printf("m:%d", m);`, from which the execution continues....

Comment: The code is doing exactly what you told it to. You're counting down from 4, with the final return at n==1, so it runs 4 times. You're correct that the part after f_b() doesn't run until after the fourth recursion, but that doesn't make it unreachable, it just runs when the three pending calls on the stack unwind.

Comment: @DavidBowling Each time it's called, it wouldn't start at the top of the function? It's starts running below the function call? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker if the part after the call f_b() isn't reached until the last call, then why does it print the statement after that 4 times?

Comment: @KaariLandry -- my wording was unclear... each time you call the function, when it returns, control is then returned to the line following the function call

Comment: Here are some youtube videos .. I haven't watched any of them but a picture usually helps: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=recursion+visualization

Comment: Yes, each time it's called it starts at the top, but it that doesn't mean each call won't continue after returning. It's like this: call(n=4), call(n=3), call(n=2), call(n=1), return(n=1), return(n=2), return(n=3), return(n=4).

Comment: So each time it is returned, it does go through the rest of the code! Okay I have that down. Now my question is why on the last recursive call, (n==1), it doesn't return a[0]. Is this not the base case and therefore what it always finishes with?

Comment: The best thing for you to do would be to use pencil and paper to write down the values of the variables in each stack frame....

Comment: @DavidBowling that is a good idea, thanks for the clarity!

Comment: The return value in main() will be the return value of the first call, not the last one.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker woah you just solved my question as far as I'm concerned. The stack resolves up but doesn't carry up any values. I was not thinking about the stack correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each recursive call the function has a return value, returning on a call later on does not jump out of the recursion to main, it just jumps out to the previous call. This is how it can reach multiple return statements.

As each call resolves on the stack, the function will complete through the rest of the code, this is how we reach code that comes after the recursive call (in f_b)

If I'm not mistaken, this function returns the smallest value in the array.